activity diagram with multiple branches with a more than 3 possible activities
I want to create an activity diagram with multiple branches with a more than 3 possible activities.
I have a doubt: Should I use an if or fork decision node?
I have an example model, but I don't know if it's correct or not:
you can see the image here

Looks Ok, except that the guards of the decision are missing.

thanks about that

I can't transform the link into picture. So far it worked well, but now Inget an error message that there would be not enough text to acompany the picture. Is this a new behavior of SO?

Ok, you may have multiple branches. The question is: do all the activities in the branches happen in the same time, or is only one branch performed at each execution ?

If 2 or more of the parallel branches shall be executed at the same time, you'd need to go for a fork node. Keep in mind that you'd then also need a join to synchronize the parallel flows.

If only one of the branch is to be selected and executed, then keep it as it is, with a decision node (which you call if but could as well be case), and a merge node at the other end.


